# Kotlin Retrofit Moshi POST request not working

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am working on an app that interfaces with an API to select from and update a MySQL database.

I am using Kotlin with Retrofit and the Moshi converter. (As I am new to learning all this stuff, this app is modified from the Mars Photo code on https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-kotlin-unit-4-pathway-2 .)

I have successfully implemented the GET part in Retrofit thanks to building out from the above tutorial, but I am having a heck of a time POSTing to the database.

The POST to update via the API works in Postman but I have tried multiple ways to replicate that in my app without success. I have tried a pretty basic POST passing in my data object (as standard Kotlin vars as well as Json annotated or SerializedName annotated), and I have tried Formurlencoded with Fields and Multipart with Parts.

I am including what I hope is all the relevant code (the latest attempt, at least). Thanks for any assistance!

```
*** My Data Class (have also tried it without the Json annoations) ***

import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class IsVotes(
    @Json(name = "is_votes") var isVotes: String,
    @Json(name = "is_id") var isId: String
        )

------

*** The function in the ViewModel file - called by a Databinded button click and using static vars for testing

   fun updateIsVotes(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // TODO: Response success var?
            try {
                IsApi.retrofitService.updateVotesAsync( IsVotes("99","5"))
                _putStatus.value = IsPutStatus.SUCCESS
            }
            catch (e:Exception) {
               _putStatus.value = IsPutStatus.ALMOST

            }
        }
    }

--------

*** The api service file and call ****

package com.viscidcreates.iswhatapi.network

import com.squareup.moshi.Moshi
import com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory
import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.*


private const val BASE_URL = "https://beamcreates.com/is_things_api/v1/"
const val getThings = "Api.php?apicall=getthings"
const val updateVotes = "Api.php?apicall=updatevotes"


private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface IsApiService {
    @GET(getthings)
    suspend fun getThings(): List<IsThing>
    
    @POST(updateVotes)
    suspend fun updateVotesAsync(@Body votes: IsVotes):  Deferred<Response<Void>>

}

object IsApi {
    val retrofitService: IsApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(IsApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you create your `@Body` classes as :

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class IsVotes(
   @Json(name = "is_votes")
   val isVotes: String,
   @Json(name = "is_id")
   val isId: String
)
```

To add the MoshiGenerator you need to add in `build.gradle`

```
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.13.0"
```

But first you should try if it's a problem of minify/obfuscation and change
`@Json(name="is_votes")` into `@field:Json(name="is_votes")` and the same for `is_id`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not have that particular dependency in my build.gradle file. And those are good insights for the dataclass. I am now getting a Build error (org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin' etc.) but I will start troubleshooting that to see what I can see and find out if your suggestions work once I can get a successful build! I will report back!

Comment: @user1673831 please use the same versioning of `moshi-kotlin-codegen` as your moshi in this case in the question I'm using 1.13.0

Comment: Ahh, yes. That got rid of the dependency related error and I was able to build successfully. Sadly, the POST is still not working with either of your suggested changes. I will keep at it! I very much appreciate your assistance!

Comment: What is the error you getting after what I suggested?

Comment: I am not getting an error, it's just not updating in the database. I assume I need to build an actual response from the POST that gives me more information. I have that catch exception block, but the response I have set for the POST is void, so it seems if I work on that I can get some usable info when it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, sure it's not returning anything since you are returning a `Void` but I think `Unit` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the time you are spending to assist! I will give that a try after I get home from my day job. :)

Comment: It's working! After the POST and data was set up correctly, it turned out it was failing due to me stupidly sending the wrong variable type but once I finished face palming, I got it all set! Thanks so much!